# Mocha not running, can't find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, mocha.js

I'm not an expert with Mocha; however, it has been running fine for all of my projects.
The other day I got the below error out of the blue:

```
> Executing task: npm run test <


> test-Scheduler@1.0.0 test C:\Users\Elijah\.projects\FullStack-apps\test-Algo
> mocha --require test/setup.js

/c/Users/Elijah/.projects/FullStack-apps/test-Algos/testing-Scheduler-algorith
/c/Users/Elijah/.projects/FullStack-apps/test-Algos/testing-Scheduler-algorith
/c/Users/Elijah/.projects/FullStack-apps/test-Algos/testing-Scheduler-algorith
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\mocha\bin\mocha'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! test-Scheduler@1.0.0 test: `mocha --require test/setup.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm                 ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test-Scheduler@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional l

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Elijah\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-06T09_17_
    The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I have other projects that are also using mocha and they are working perfectly fine, it's just this one server and I can't figure out how to fix it?

Any help would be much appreciated. If other info is required for this to be answered, please let me know.

I've reinstalled npm, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you check your package.json file and see if mocha is there or not in the list of dependencies? Or have you checked if mocha is installed globally (not preferred )?

Comment: From what I see, the file is there and I just checked and yes, it is installed globally. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Never mind, I just uninstalled it globally then installed it as a dev dependency and am still getting the error

Comment: It looks like it's using the globally installed mocha from your code window. Did that change? Mocha should reside in your application as dependency. The first output shows us there is something fishy with the PATH probably: "Error: Cannot find module 'C:\mocha\bin\mocha'"

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed after uninstalling globally and installing as a dependency.

Comment: if you installed as `devDependency` then point your package.json test script to look in `node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha`